# Proving that all real numbers lie in Fatou set of $f(z)=\sin(z)/3$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-dynamics

The problem is this:

Define the entire function $f$ by $$f(z)=\frac{\text{sin}(z)}{3}.$$
Show that all real numbers lie in the Fatou set $F_f$.

*Hint*: For $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we have $|\text{sin}(x)|\leq |x|$.

I have managed to show that all multiples of $\pi$ are in the Fatou set using complete invariance, since 0 is a fixpoint and these all map to 0. Also that the iterates tend to 0 for all real x, using the hint. But this does not immediately imply that they are in the Fatou set, does it?

Beyond that, I am a bit stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All you need to add is that complex numbers sufficiently close to the real line also tend to zero upon iteration, this could probably be done using the continuity, maybe have to use uniform continuity, of sin to extend the bound $|sin x|<|x|$ to a bound $\frac {|sin x|}{3}<|x|$ in some region near the real line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $|f'(0)| = \frac 13 < 1$ so that $z=0$ is an attracting fixed point of $f$, and some disk $B_r(0)$ is contained in the Fatou set $F(f)$.

Then, as you noticed, for every $x \in \Bbb R$ the iterates $f^{n}(x)$ converge to zero for $n \to \infty$. It follows that $f^{n}(x) \in B_r(0) \subset F(f)$ for some $n$, and therefore $x \in F(f)$ because of the invariance of the Fatou set.